# Chrome - Password/Credit Card input within an iFrame

Tags: ssl, iframe, secure-context

I am using an iFrame which is hosted on another domain that has an SSL certificate. On the page where the iFrame is used I get 'Not Secure' message next to the domain in Google Chrome and the following warning in the console log:

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure
>   context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more
>   information.

**Note**: The iFrame loads an online booking portal which includes both login details and credit card information.

In order to prevent this message from showing, would I need to purchase an SSL certificate?

I'm asking because I don't want to order one if it doesn't resolve the issue, there is a way around this without having to get a SSL certificate or if it's just not worth getting one for this situation.

Your thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> To help users browse the web safely, Chrome indicates connection
>   security with an icon in the address bar. Historically, Chrome has not
>   explicitly labelled HTTP connections as non-secure. Beginning in
>   January 2017 (Chrome 56), we’ll mark HTTP pages that collect passwords
>   or credit cards as non-secure, as part of a long-term plan to mark all
>   HTTP sites as non-secure.

**It applies to all sites that are not https.**

Do check for any website which have login information and doesn't have https, you can view the username and password in the chrome developer window.

[security page documentation](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/09/moving-towards-more-secure-web.html)